# Hiding pseudo css element when data attribute is empty

Tags: css

I have the following badge that I can add to any element:

```
.notification-badge {
  position: relative;
}

.notification-badge:after {
  content:attr(data-badge);
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
  right:-10px;
  min-width: 10px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: $brand-danger;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

It's fairly straightforward, the element that I attach the badge class onto provides a data-badge attribute with some number, which gets shoved into the `:after` element's content.

I would like the badge to not appear at all if `content` is empty. I've tried using the :empty selector, but it doesn't work because the actual tag may still contain other elements, for instance:

```
<a href="/cart" class="notification-badge" data-badge="">
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
</a>
```

In this case, I'd want the shopping cart icon and link to still exist, but have the notification-badge class not render the badge.

So, I suppose I could give up on the idea of it being a pure pseudo element and just make it a span with the number inside of it instead of a data- attribute, but it seems like there is probably an easy way to do this that I'm just not aware of.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
.notification-badge:after {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.notification-badge[data-badge]:after {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:empty` selector selector matches every element that has no children (including text nodes) [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp)

So what you could do is here do something like this:

```
.notification-bade .fa-shopping-cart {visibility:visible}
.notification-badge:after {
content:attr(data-badge); visibility: hidden
}
```